# Why 'if not s' and 's ~= nil' are different?

Tags: lua

In Lua, I have written the following:

```
for s in string.gmatch(path, "([^'\\']+)") do
    if not s then -- if s ~= nil then
        table.insert(path_tb, s)
        print(s)
    end
end
```

If I replace `if not s then` with `if s ~= nil then` I get a different result. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: `if s ~= nil then` is almost equivalent to `if s then`

Comment: What is the value of path?

Comment: I don't see how either is useful to use on iterator variable values resulting from iterating over [`string.gmatch`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch). `s` will always be string (which is never falsey when empty and is never `nil`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not s` is true exactly when `s` is nil or `s` is false.